# What is wrong in this code related to pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, operator-precedence, dereference

```
/* The structure of the Linked list Node is as follows:

struct Node
{
    int val;
    struct Node *next;

    Node(int data){
        val = data;
        next = NULL;
    }

}; 
*/

void intersection(Node **head1, Node **head2,Node **head3)
{

    cout<<*head1->val;
}
```

The above code in not working but when I take another pointer  `Node* h1=*head1;` and then print its value its working fine. In both codes the value I want to print is same then why above code is wrong;

```
/* The structure of the Linked list Node is as follows:

struct Node
{
    int val;
    struct Node *next;

    Node(int data){
        val = data;
        next = NULL;
    }

}; 
*/

void intersection(Node **head1, Node **head2,Node **head3)
{

    Node* h1=*head1;
    cout<<h1->val;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and explain what is the meaning of "not working"

Comment: @idclev463035818 this is not complete code. the comment block is just for clarity of reader about the structure of linked list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code snippet

```
void intersection(Node **head1, Node **head2,Node **head3)
{

    cout<<*head1->val;
}
```

the expression

```
*head1->val
```

is equivalent to

```
*( head1->val )
```

(because the postfix operator -> has higher priority than the unary operator *) but the pointer `head` does not point to an object of the structure type. It points to another pointer, You have to write

```
( *head1 )->val
```

This is equivalent to the expression with  the intermediate variable `h1`

```
Node* h1 = ( *head1 );
h1->val;
```

To make the difference more visible you can rewrite the expression of accessing the data member `val` the following way

```
( **head ).val
```

that is now the expression `**head` yields the `lvalue` of an object of the type `struct Node`.

Or using an intermediate variable like

```
Node *h1 = *head;
( *( h1 ) ).val
     ^
     |
   *head
```

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence puts `->` before `*`. For illustration:

```
#include<iostream>

struct foo {
    int x;
};

int main() { 
    foo f;
    foo* fp = &f;
    foo** fpp = &fp;

    auto& xref = f.x;

    std::cout << &xref << "\n";
    //std::cout << *fpp->x;      // error
    std::cout << &(*fpp)->x;
}
```

The line marked as `//error` does not compile, beceause `fpp` has no member `x`. The other two lines print the same address, that of `f.x`.